# robots.txt disallow google bot on root domain but allow google image bot?

Tags: robots.txt

Would having the following robot.txt work?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Allow: /
```

My idea is to avoid google crawling my cdn domain but allowing google image still crawl and index my images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file has to be called `robots.txt`, not `robot.txt`.

Note that `User-agent: *` targets *all* bots (that are not matched by another `User-agent` record), not only the Googlebot. So if you want allow other bots to crawl your site, you would want to use `User-agent: Googlebot` instead.

So this robots.txt would allow "Googlebot-Image" everything, and disallow everything for all other bots:

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

(Note that `Disallow:` with an empty string value is equivalent to `Allow: /`, but the `Allow` field is not part of the original robots.txt specification, although some parsers support it, among them Google’s).